# jQuery locationpicker input style background and focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery locationpicker in a webapp and it seems to block some styling for the input. I can change the width, padding, border, etc, but there's problem with the background for which I must use jQuery to change.

The input:

```
<input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search:">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#search-text').css({
    background: 'transparent'
}).locationpicker({
    location: {latitude: 0, longitude: 0},
    inputBinding: {
    latitudeInput: $('#lat'),
    longitudeInput: $('#lng'),
    locationNameInput: $(address)
}, enableAutocomplete: true
});
```

The CSS :focus does not work either to change background:

```
#search-text:focus {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

But this is working:

```
#search-text:focus {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Any ideas why there's problem with the background style?

Comment: Try add `background: #FFFFFF; !important`

Comment: @CMedina Thank you, got it working now :)

Comment: No problem, accept the answer and close question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `!important` for your rule in CSS:

```
background: #FFFFFF; !important
```

If there are other rules will make no effect on your element.